# After translating node The layout x and y stays the same

Tags: javafx

I currently have some stack panes on a pane and when dragged with a mouse they move around the pane. I do this by getting the coordinate of the mouse 
 and the translate x and y of the stack pane when I press the the stack pane. Then when I start to drag the stack pane I set the the translation x and y of the stack pane to the mouse coordinates when I pressed the stack pane + the difference of the new mouse coordinates and the old mouse coordinates.

My problem is after dragging the StackPane the layout x and y stays the same I want to update this as I used this else where.

My event handler when you press the StackPane:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMousePressedEventHandler = 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {

                currentStackPane  = ((StackPane)(t.getSource()));
                orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
                orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
                layoutX =  currentStackPane.getLayoutX();
                layoutY =  currentStackPane.getLayoutY();

            }
        };
```

My event handler when i drag the StackPane:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseDraggedEventHandler = 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {


                double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
                double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
                currentStackPane.setTranslateX(offsetX);
                currentStackPane.setTranslateY(offsetY);
             }
        };
```

I tried make a event handler after the drag is finished:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> circleOnMouseReleasedEventHandler = 
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {

                currentStackPane.setLayoutX(layoutX + ((StackPane)(t.getSource())).getTranslateX());
                currentStackPane.setLayoutY(layoutY + ((StackPane)(t.getSource())).getTranslateY());
                currentStackPane.setTranslateX(0);
                currentStackPane.setTranslateY(0);
        }
};
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

EDIT:

I have changed my event handlers. It seems to be updating the layout x and y correctly for the first time I drag the stack pane but when i first drag the stack pane and then release the mouse the stackpane moves to a different position then every time i drag after it messes up completely. Not sure why, any help appreciated!

EDIT2: I realised I set translate x to 0 but didnt set translate y to 0 in the mouse released event. It all works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the problem, I would first recommend to have a look at the documentation of layoutX/layoutY properties of a Node.

> public final DoubleProperty layoutXProperty
>
> Defines the x coordinate of the translation that is added to this
>   Node's transform for the purpose of layout. The value should be
>   computed as the offset required to adjust the position of the node
>   from its current layoutBounds minX position (which might not be 0) to
>   the desired location.
>
> For example, if textnode should be positioned at finalX
>
> ```
>  textnode.setLayoutX(finalX - textnode.getLayoutBounds().getMinX());
> ```
>
> Failure to subtract layoutBounds minX may result in misplacement of
>   the node. The relocate(x, y) method will automatically do the correct
>   computation and should generally be used over setting layoutX
>   directly.
>
> The node's final translation will be computed as layoutX + translateX,
>   where layoutX establishes the node's stable position and translateX
>   optionally makes dynamic adjustments to that position.
>
> If the node is managed and has a Region as its parent, then the layout
>   region will set layoutX according to its own layout policy. If the
>   node is unmanaged or parented by a Group, then the application may set
>   layoutX directly to position it.

In short,for every node that is rendered in the scene, its position is actually a sum of its layoutX/Y and translateX/Y values in relative to its parent node. The layoutX/Y are initially updated as per its parents layout policy. For that reason, there is no point in updating/relying on layoutX/Y values of node, **IF** its parent (eg,.StackPane,HBox,VBox,..etc) manages it position.

Pane will not manage/decide its children layout. For that reason the default layoutX/Y values of its children is always 0.

From the above info,if we now look into your code, you are updating the translate values and setting the layout values wrongly. Instead what you have to actually do is:

1. Take intial values of layoutX/Y.
2. Update the translateX/Y while dragging.
3. And on mouse released recompute layoutX/Y values and reset
   translateX/Y values.

Below is a quick demo of what I have described.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PaneLayoutDemo extends Application {
    double sceneX, sceneY, layoutX, layoutY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();
        root.getChildren().addAll(getBox("green"), getBox("red"), getBox("yellow"));
    }

    private StackPane getBox(String color) {
        StackPane box = new StackPane();
        box.getChildren().add(new Label("Drag me !!"));
        box.setStyle("-fx-background-color:" + color + ";-fx-border-width:2px;-fx-border-color:black;");
        box.setPrefSize(150, 150);
        box.setMaxSize(150, 150);
        box.setMinSize(150, 150);
        box.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            sceneX = e.getSceneX();
            sceneY = e.getSceneY();
            layoutX = box.getLayoutX();
            layoutY = box.getLayoutY();
            System.out.println(color.toUpperCase() + " Box onStart :: layoutX ::" + layoutX + ", layoutY::" + layoutY);
        });
        box.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double offsetX = e.getSceneX() - sceneX;
            double offsetY = e.getSceneY() - sceneY;
            box.setTranslateX(offsetX);
            box.setTranslateY(offsetY);
        });
        box.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            // Updating the new layout positions
            box.setLayoutX(layoutX + box.getTranslateX());
            box.setLayoutY(layoutY + box.getTranslateY());

            // Resetting the translate positions
            box.setTranslateX(0);
            box.setTranslateY(0);
        });
        return box;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Once you are familiar with the demo, try changing the root from Pane to StackPane and see the behaviour difference.

Comment: Hi Sai. Thank you for the answer I really appreciate it. I took your example and tried to implement it in my solution however it doesn't seem to work as expected. I have added an edit to my post it would be great if you could check my code out to see if I missed something. Thanks

Comment: Glad that it worked :) Can you please update the question as Answered if it solves your problem.